# How to increase the image twice with the animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

I want to move the image and simultaneously increase it twice. But how can I enlarge the image specifying its original dimensions as the 100%? I tried to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="100%p"
        android:fromYScale="100%p"
        android:toXScale="150%p"
        android:toYScale="150%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100" />
</set>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit more please? You say you want to move your image and increase its size to double size at the same time. Now what's your problem? Did you load that animation in your code?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky yes, I have implemented it in code. In short, I want to achieve this result: http://s3.postimg.org/odge92qcj/1441469931951.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="100%"
        android:fromYScale="100%"
        android:toXScale="150%"
        android:toYScale="150%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100" />
</set>
```

That should work fine. Make sure you load it in your code.